# DatePicker will not update when culture is changed

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

I have an application where I can change the culture. However, when I actually change it, the datepickers in said application don't change their date formats. I've tried hiding them and then reshowing them. That doesn't work.

Can anyone help?

The code:

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString());
ci.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = SomeClass.isDDMM ? "dd/MM/yy" : "MM/dd/yy";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
```

Comment: can you show an example of your code..? are you using any `dateTimePicker.CustomFormat` for example..?

Comment: No, I'm just directly changing Thread.CurrentCulture.

Comment: can you show how you are doing that and the code you are using .. what date format are you trying to change it to.. can you try something like the following `dateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker.CustomFormat = Application.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;` for example

Comment: No, I'm just leaving the datepickers to realize that I want the current culture!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be some kind of issue with the `DatePicker` when changing the current culture. It will not properly refresh the value immediately, but when you focus it and remove the focus from it again, the new date format will be applied.

The only way I have found to fix this without too much trouble is this:

```
var date = t.SelectedDate;
t.SelectedDate = null;
t.SelectedDate = date;
```

That is not very elegant, but should work ok.

This small program shows how the format is changing when a button is clicked.
The XAML just contains a `DatePicker` called `dtp` and a button.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private string format1 = "MM/dd/yy";
    private string format2 = "dd/MM/yy";
    private string currentFormat = null;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        currentFormat = format1;
    }

    private void clickButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString());

        ci.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = currentFormat =
            currentFormat == format1 ? format2 : format1;

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;

        //Refresh control..
        var date = dtp.SelectedDate;
        dtp.SelectedDate = null;
        dtp.SelectedDate = date;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ofstream But I assume the right format is used when you have changed the culture and then select a new date in the DatePicker? Or can't you get it to show the new format at all?

Comment: Well, I don't know whats wrong then. Take a look at my update to the answer. It contains a small program that works. You must be doing something differently.

Comment: Hmm, fixed it. Seems I was inadvertedly running it on another thread.

Comment: +1 for using temporary var for date.  Causes 2 notifies, but much better than not having my date slashes turned to periods immediately on culture change.

Comment: Just letting everybody know, this is still the case and this solution still works!